# Missing key for conditional render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I have an array of elements which I'm rendering based on state. Works in dev but when push to vercel, build error shows `Missing "key" prop for element in array`. I don't have any mapping function. What am I missing?

```
interface Props {
    method: string
    email: string
}

export default function Instructions({method, email}: Props){
    const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);

    const instruct: Instruct = {
        'Gmail': {
            steps: [
                <p>Login to Gmail. Click on Setting logo (gear button at top right) and &apos;See all settings&apos;</p>,
                <p>Under &apos;Forwarding and POP/IMAP&apos;, add a forwarding address</p>,
            ]
        },
        'HSBC': {
            emailRules:
                <div>
                    <p className="mt-2"><span className="font-bold">Name: </span>Parse HSBC</p>
                    <p className="mt-2">Click save</p>
                </div>
                ,
            steps: [
                <p>Login to HSBC and speak to chat bot. Request for live agent and ask to turn on email notifications.</p>
            ]
        }
    }

    let steps = instruct[method].steps.concat(instruct[email].steps).concat(instruct[method].emailRules!)
    
    return (
  
        <div>
            <div>
                <p className="font-bold underline">Step {currentImage+1}</p>
                {steps[currentImage]}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React's requirement is to provide a unique key prop for elements generated within a loop or when rendering elements from an array. In your case, you are not using a mapping function to directly iterate over the steps array, but you're still rendering elements from an array. I am assuming may be it is still required that you provide a key prop when rendering elements from an array? You can try providing a unique key and test if this is indeed the case.

```js
'Gmail': {
 steps: [
     <p key="step1">Login to Gmail. Click on Setting logo (gear button at top right) and 'See all settings'</p>,
     <p key="step2">Under 'Forwarding and POP/IMAP', add a forwarding address</p>,
 ]
},
'HSBC': {
 emailRules:
     <div key="emailRules">
       ...
     </div>,
 steps: [
     <p key="step3">Login to HSBC and speak to chat bot. Request for live agent and ask to turn on email notifications.</p>
 ]
}
```